# How to create a table with agregate of the day , transposing a column which would generate duplicates in order to break down the reservations status

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pivot-table

I hope you can help me. I would like to create a new dataframe with the stay date agregation (count), also I wanted to transpose the rate codes column which would be duplicate given that they would be breaken down by reservation status

| stay | status | ratec |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | cancel | BA1 |
| 02/01 | active | AR2 |
| 03/01 | active | P12 |
| 03/01 | cancel | P12 |
| 01/01 | active | AR2 |
| 02/01 | active | AR2 |

I would like to transform the table like this (count of cancelled, no show and active separated):
| stay | BA1ACT | AR2ACT|P12ACT| BA1 CA | P12 CA|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 01/01| 1      | 1     | 0    | 0      | 0     |
| 02/01| 0      | 2     | 0    | 0      | 0     |
| 03/01| 0      | 0     | 1    | 0      | 1     |

I tried this df = df.groupby(["stay","ratec"])['status'].aggregate(lambda x: x.nunique()).unstack()

but did not work..

Would you be able to help me? Thanks in advance!